# Question about $x \sin(1/x)$ at $x = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

I know that $f(x) = \sin(1/x)x$ takes the value $0$ at $x=0$. What else can we say about the function $f(x)$ at $x=0$? More specifically, is $f$  continuous at $x=0$? Is it even differentiable at $x=0$? Thank you!

Comment: $f(x)= x \sin(1/x)$ *does not* take value $0$ at $x=0$. It is undefined there.

Comment: Is this a `real-analysis` question? Or a `complex-analysis` one?

Comment: No. $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$. However, discontinuity at $x=0$ is removable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function $f(x)= x \sin(1/x)$ is not $0$ at $x=0$ as it is not even defined there. But it does have a removable discontinuity there, i.e. $\lim_{x \to 0} x \sin(1/x)=0$. You can easily prove this using Squeeze Theorem, comparing $f(x)$ to $|x|$ because $|\sin(1/x)| \leq 1$.

So what I think you mean to ask is 
$$
f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
x\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right),& x \neq 0 \\
0,& x=0
\end{cases}
$$
continuous or differentiable at $x=0$. The answer is yes to continuous and a no to differentiable. Obviously, $f(x)$ is continuous/differentiable for all $x \neq 0$. The only question is what happens at $x=0$, where it is continuous but not differentiable. I would try these both. For continuity, you essentially just need to use a Squeeze Theorem argument for continuity. For differentiability, simply use the definition of the derivative. You can find the continuity argument [at this link](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-prove-that-the-function-xsin-1-x-is-continuous-at-x-0) and the differentiable one [at this link](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~rogness/mathlets/xSin1overX/).

Answer (score 2):

$f:x\mapsto x\,\sin(1/x)$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^\star$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$ without the element $0$, since the argument of the sinus is not defined for $x=0$. However you can define an extension on $\mathbb{R}$, $\bar{f}$, to be equal to $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^\star$ and such that $\bar{f}(0)=0$. I guess in your question you were referring to $\bar{f}$.

$\bar f$ is continuous in $0$, since $|\sin |\leq 1$, so $|\bar f|\leq |x|$.

$\bar f$ is not differentiable in $0$. Indeed $\bar f(\varepsilon)/\varepsilon = \sin(1/\varepsilon)$ on $\mathbb{R}^\star$, which has no limit for $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)$ is not 'defined' at $x=0$. So, it **does not** take the value $0$ at it. So you will find a discontinuity here, and hence its non-differentiable there.

---

However, if you define a function :

$$g(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{11} x\sin\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0   \end{array} \right.$$

This will make it continuous.

Also,

$$g'(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{11} \sin\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)-\frac{1}{x}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x} \right) &x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{array}  \right.$$

the derivative near $x=0$ is not defined here. So its not differentiable.

**NOTE:** Above method for checking differentiability is not the "correct" approach. It is more of a problem solving trick. To do it the "correct" way, :

$$g'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(0+h) -g(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right) = undefined$$

Also [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xkmxcuxjxh) is a link to the function $f(x)$'s graph...which I feel is quite interesting.

Comment: You say the derivative near $0$ is not defined yet you just defined $g'(0)=0$. I think what you mean is $g'(x)= \sin(1/x) - 1/x \cos(1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and just that - leaving $x=0$ out of it because $g'(x)$ is not defined there. The answer rather implies that the derivative of a piecewise function is the derivative of the pieces - so long as they agree in limits. But that's forcing continuity as well, and derivatives need not be continuous. Though this approach works well enough for 'class problem' Math as the approach will work as a method of getting to the solution.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life yes I suppose....I just got used to this method.....I'll edit to improve the post